# Which media conditions are allowed in image sizes attribute?

Tags: html, image, attributes, media-queries, amp-html

I'm trying to figure out which media conditions are allowed in HTML `img` sizes attribute.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<img
class="cover"
alt="'. $hero_image_alt .'"
src="'. $hero_img_url_530w[0] .'"
srcset="'. $hero_img_url_360w[0] .' 360w,
        '. $hero_img_url_1470w[0] .' 1470w"
sizes="(min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-width: 480px) 360px,
       (min-device-width: 481px) 1470px,
       1470px"
disable-inline-width data-hero />
```

When I am inspecting the page in responsive mode my code works for all devices with `DPR:2` (screenshot 1) as well as `DPR:1`. When I am switching to a device with `DPR:3` sizes media stops working (screenshot 2). Maybe the `sizes` attribute is not working at all and it just takes the most suitable image from `srcset` and as soon as DPR is 3 that means that logical width is `360px * 3dpr = 1080px` - 1470w image is used. Can I use something like `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` or `(min-resolution: 72dpi)` in sizes media to have more advanced control?

*screenshot 1*
[image]

*screenshot 2*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution so far is it use DPR values in `srcset` and get rid of `sizes`. The only problem with that solution is that it is going to use 990w image on `DPR:2` mobile screens, like iphone 6/7/8

```
<img
class="cover pos-left-top"
alt="'. $hero_image_alt .'"
src="'. $hero_img_url_530w[0] .'"
srcset="'. $hero_img_url_375w[0] .' 3x,
        '. $hero_img_url_768w[0] .' 3.5x,
        '. $hero_img_url_990w[0] .' 2x,
        '. $hero_img_url_1470w[0] .'"
disable-inline-width data-hero />
```